# Convert UTF8 Text and Numbers to UTF16-BE for Clickatell

Tags: php, utf-8, encode, utf-16

I use an online sms service (Clickatell) for a web app i use. My main language is Greek, so i need to convert in my php file the sms text to UTF-16BE before i send it. For example i need to convert the text

"Το ραντεβού σας έχει μεταφερθεί στις 12-12-2016 και ώρα 18:25"

to

03a403bf002003c103b103bd03c403b503b203bf03cd002003c303b103c2002003ad03c703b503b9002003bc03b503c403b103c603b503c103b803b503af002003c303c403b903c2002000310032002d00310032002d0032003000310036002003ba03b103b9002003ce03c103b1002000310038003a00320035

I need to conver everything inluding spaces, symbols and numbers. 
I have found a few php commands but they are converting only the text.

```
    $text=strtoupper(str_replace(array('"', '\u'), array('',''), json_encode('Το ραντεβού σας έχει μεταφερθεί στις 12-12-2016 και ώρα 18:25')));
```

When using the above code I get the below result:

03A403BF 03C103B103BD03C403B503B203BF03CD 03C303B103C2 03AD03C703B503B9 03BC03B503C403B103C603B503C103B803B503AF 03C303C403B903C2 12-12-2016 03BA03B103B9 03CE03C103B1 18:25

If you notice the date and time as well as all the spaces are not in unicode.

**Can anyone tell me how to get my whole phrase in unicode? How can i do this with php?**
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [mcve] of what you have already tried and are having a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "they are converting only the text", but if you're looking to convert a `UTF-8` string to `UTF-16BE`, then you can try:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', $string);
```

or..

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8');
```

Edit:

Since you've shared some code now, your technique for conversion is not sound, unless you really want it represented like you have it. Your result is basically a hex representation of the individual bytes, but not the bytes themselves.

Edit 2:

If you genuinely need it in the format specified, the following will do it for you:

```
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', $string); // .. or mb_convert_encoding
$converted = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    $converted .= sprintf('%02X', ord($string[$i]));
}
```

Comment: When i use the code that i added above i get the below result
03A403BF 03C103B103BD03C403B503B203BF03CD 03C303B103C2 03AD03C703B503B9 03BC03B503C403B103C603B503C103B803B503AF 03C303C403B903C2 12-12-2016 03BA03B103B9 03CE03C103B1 18:25

Comment: If you notice the date and time as well all the spaces are not converted. 
Thank you i tried your silution but i get weird characters and question marks

Comment: `ASCII` values were assigned codepoints which tie back to their original encoding under ASCII. `UTF-8` is backwards compatible with `ASCII`. `UTF-16` uses 2/4 bytes to encode codepoints, 2 in the case BMP characters (including ASCII). E.g. encoding the value `5` results in `\x00\x35`. `\x35` is valid `UTF-8`, and represents `5` as well. The `\x00` is treated as `NULL`.

Comment: RE my solution resulting in weird chatacters: that is to be expected really, as wherever you're printing it (browser or terminal) is probably setup to expect UTF-8. What you're seeing is UTF-16 rendered as if it were UTF-8. That doesn't mean the string is not correctly encoded though.

Comment: For some reason i cannot get it to work. The closest i got was with the code i posted above. Basically what i need is some code to replicate exactly what this site is doing https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter with the options Convert whitespace characters "enabled" and Remove \u "enabled". I need all the content of the message in unicode utf16-BE. Everything i have found encodes only the text. 
Sorry if repeat my self but i cannot fully understand what you are saying above and what i should do.

Comment: I try sending the message with your solution and i get scrambled text

Comment: I've added some code which generates a string in the format you've been describing. But without seeing what you're actually calling into, it's hard for me to know if that's what is really required. But anyway, just to clarify - that code is generating a string which contains the hex representation of the bytes used to encode it as UTF-16BE. But it is not the raw bytes of a UTF-16BE string.

Comment: Man you just made my day! I have been struggling with this for 48 hours! I am not so good with php but i;ll get there! If you ever find you self in athens i will buy you a coffee! Thanks a lot!